# Question on dyadic subdivision and notation: Rudin 2.40

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question

This is moreso a question on notation. Rudin's proof Theorem 2.40 states that $k$-cells are compact. He begins with a $k$-cell $I = \prod\limits_{i=1}^k [a_i, b_i]$. He later subdivides $I$ dyadically by letting $c_i = \frac{a_i + b_i}{2}$. Rudin states that the union of these $2^k$ $k$-cells yields $I$. My question is whether it is equivalent to notate this as
$$
\prod\limits_{i=1}^k [a_i, c_i] \times [c_i, b_i].
$$
In this case, I'd be asserting that this product is "equal" to the union of these $2^k$ cells, which doesn't make complete sense to me.

Are these in fact equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your notation conveys what you want it to convey. It's certainly true that$$\prod\limits_{i=1}^k [a_i, b_i] = \prod\limits_{i=1}^k \bigl( [a_i, c_i] \cup [c_i, b_i] \bigr)$$with $\cup$ instead of $\times$. But writing all $2^k$ cells is difficult to do with this notation. Even when $k=2$ we already must write$$[a_1,b_1]\times[a_2,b_2]=\bigl([a_1,c_1]\times[a_2,c_2]\bigr)\cup\bigl([c_1,b_1]\times[a_2,c_2]\bigr)\cup\bigl([a_1,c_1]\times[c_2,b_2]\bigr)\cup\bigl([c_1,b_1]\times[c_2,b_2]\bigr).$$